# Getting an error when running this code

Tags: solidity

when I run this code I get the error "call to Voting.candidates errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.0.8)" anybody know how to fix this or what is means??

```
contract Voting {
    
    ///@dev keeps track of the voter candidates' info
    struct VoterCandidate {
        string voterName;
        uint voterAge;
    }
    
    ///@dev keeps track of all the candidates
    VoterCandidate[] public candidates;

    ///@dev creates a new "VoterCandidate" and adds a the candidate to the array of candidates
    function candidateRegistration(string memory _voterName, uint _voterAge) public {
        VoterCandidate memory newCandidate;
        newCandidate.voterName = _voterName;
        newCandidate.voterAge = _voterAge;
        candidates.push(newCandidate);
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you compiling in Remix or with something like Truffle? What does your function call look like? If you are calling the function with javascript/web3 it could potentially be that you're not using '' around the number and instead passing it in as an integer. You might be doing

```
Voting.methods.candidateRegistration("billy", 25);
```

as opposed to

```
Voting.methods.candidateRegistration("billy",'25');
```